# Are you clever enough? In memory of Avigrail

Tags: riddle, word

*This riddle is dedicated to **Avigrail**, a brilliant riddler.*

There are four parts to this puzzle. Each of them points towards the same solution, and you can get the solution from any one on its own, but I'll only accept an answer that includes explanations of *how* to solve all four.

This is the *interesting* one (also probably the easiest):

> for all Lambda unique e L for all unique r

In this riddle, all the clues point towards the *concept* of the answer:

> I might be metal, or you might
>   Find me in woods or at the beach.
>   I can answer your questions -
>   Always truly, but oft unwelcome.

In this riddle, all the clues point towards the *English word* for the answer:

> I might be paper.
>   Half of me has it;
>   Or, with repeats,
>   Only one lacks it.

In this riddle, all the clues point towards the *German word* for the answer:

> I might be paper.
>   I rhyme with a predator.
>   Bond a fork and then
>   A twisted limb frozen.

Comment: Given [this edit](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/6538/3) I suspect the political statement is more important than the riddle to you.

Comment: @JonEricson You suspect wrongly then. I spent a long time composing the riddle and only thought of including the first paragraph at the last moment.

Comment: @JonEricson Closing a question because it contains the word 'predator' is really not on. I think I'm going to create a meta post about this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer is

> mirror

which I got starting with the German word bit:

> Predator - eagle. German words rhyming with 'eagle' - siegel (seal) and spiegel (mirror), both ending with "gel", a twist of "leg", which is encouraging, and only the latter names a newspaper, *Der Spiegel*. That explains lines 1, 2 and 4 and leaves line 3. A [pie fork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastry_fork) is a kind of fork, and if "s" refers to a type of [sigma bond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma_bond), then "Bond a fork" gives "Spie" and we've got "Spie" + "gel" - tick!

The English word bit:

> *The Mirror* is an English-language newspaper. "Half of me" is "m". "Or, with repeats" is "or" plus "rr", a doubling of the letter "R" used for "repeat". That gives m+or+rr and the last line tells us that only "one" is lacking, meaning the letter "i". m+or+rr+i gives "mirror".

What's going on with the flip of the string of symbols to give "Avigrail" is

> mirroring

Now the first bit:

> A mirror might be metal, and can reflect accurately even if to do so is often unwelcome. Which leaves "you might / Find me in woods or at the beach" - possibly meaning reflection in a lake or the sea?

Answer (score 4):

For the first part,

> for all Lambda unique e L for all unique r

can be rendered as

$$ \forall \Lambda ! e \mathrm{L} \forall ! \mathrm{r} $$

which seems to spell "Avigrail" if you flip each letter.

Comment: The L could be a T

Comment: Or if numbers exist, l could be t and e could be 9/6 somehow

Comment: Why the $\exists$ signs?

Comment: @randal'thor I thought "unique" was shorthand for "there exists a single", but I guess you can have the `!` separately. Removing the E's makes it easier to see the answer.

Comment: *It's late and maybe I've had a glass wine too many*, but the 2nd riddle somehow reminds me of *anvil* with some similarity to Avi(grai)l?  *Yes, too much wine...*

Comment: xnor, you've more or less solved the first part - well done! You haven't written down the one-word answer, but look at what's going on when you solve that first part. If you're still stuck, try the second part. The third and fourth are really hard and mainly there for confirmation. @BmyGuest - no, it's not anvil (and do poke me if I forget to come back to your really cool visual puzzle!)

Comment: Keep going @xnor! Don't be discouraged by Jon Ericson's vandalism; I promise 'predator' is nothing to do with moderators or any other people :-)

Comment: @randal'thor I'm thinking about it, but I seem to be stuck. I've never been good at oblique riddley clues.